# Why does Morpheus believe Neo is the One

Tags: plot-explanation, the-matrix

Is it ever stated in any of the films or in the animatrix why Morpheus persued and was certain that Neo was the one before even meeting him.

He seemed to have made his decision that Neo was the One before setting him free but why?

Considering Neo's life before being introduced - He had a simple job, okay he was also a hacker (but who isn't nowadays), they never show him with any high moral standing or physical attributes, so why him?

Please use evidence from source material and not simply speculation

Comment: At least the oracle told him that he was to find the chosen one, I think (this was mentioned in the 1st movie if I remember correctly). Though, I'm not sure if she also told him *who* the chosen one was.

Comment: @SonnyBurnett She definately didn't considering that she didnt know, that is why all the kids were there in her apartment they were all hopefuls

Answer (score 10):

The Original Movie script (post adaptation) sheds some light on this:

> I believed that all I had to do was
>   point my finger and anoint whoever
>   I chose. I was wrong, Neo.
>   Terribly wrong. Not a day or night
>   passes that I do not think of them.
>   After the fifth, I lost my way. I
>   doubted everything the Oracle had
>   said. I doubted myself.
>
> And then I saw you, on the Net, searching for me and everything
>   changed. I felt this charge, this electricity through my whole body. I
>   started laughing and tears poured out of my eyes, because I knew, I
>   knew that you were the One.

As you allude to in the phrasing of your question, Morpheus *doesn't know* who the one is, but he **believes** it to be Neo; and for Morpheus, belief is everything. It can move Mountains.

Interestingly, Neo is not the first 'One' that Morpheus has discovered, and there have been at least 5 other candidates of his selection:

> **CYPHER** I'm going to let you in on a little secret here. Now don't tell
>   him I told you this, but this ain't the first time Morpheus thought he
>   found the One.
>
> **NEO** Really?
>
> **CYPHER** You bet your ass. It keeps him going. Maybe it keeps all of us
>   going.
>
> **NEO** How many were there?
>
> **CYPHER** Five. Since I've been here.
>
> **NEO** What happened to them?
>
> **CYPHER** Dead. All dead.
>
> **NEO** How?
>
> **CYPHER** Honestly. Morpheus. He got them all amped up believing in
>   bullshit. I watched each of them take on an agent and I watched each
>   of them die. Little piece of advice: you see an agent, you do what we
>   do; run. Run your ass off.

It seems that Morpheus method of choice for initiating potential candidates is to remove the possibility of doubt that they may not be the one, and supplant it with absolute faith. Perhaps, as is proven to be true, The One cannot manifest their true potential unless they undergo 'a revelation', and this is only possible without doubt.

This blind faith could perhaps be a subterfuge by Morpheus to encourage The One, which would go some way to explaining why he appears shocked, dumbfounded even, when it emerges that Neo is infact The One.

Comment: You can see why they left this out of the final script. It is clearly better not to explain everything to the audience.